# SharpDX WPF with SwapChain

Tags: wpf, directx, directx-11, sharpdx

All SharpDX implementations with WPF seems to be using the D3DImage instead of creating a swapchain. I understand this could be troublesome on heavy rendering causing flickering.

I created a Swapchain like this:

```
var desc = new SwapChainDescription() {
                BufferCount = 1,
                ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(width, height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),//sview
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = handle,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };

            FeatureLevel[] levels = new FeatureLevel[] { FeatureLevel.Level_11_0, FeatureLevel.Level_10_1, FeatureLevel.Level_10_0 };

            DeviceCreationFlags flag = DeviceCreationFlags.None;

            Device11.CreateWithSwapChain(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, flag, levels, desc, out _device, out _swapchain);
```

handle being a IntPtr to my WPF window, retrieved like this:

```
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
```

It seems to work, I can clear the window and run Present on the device.
Does this mean I'm rendering as a "normal" Game object or RenderForm now or is the windowHandle just pointing to a D3DImage?

Edit. 
I have realised that all controls on that window disappear when I run Present() on the device. Perhaps that's the reason why you can't do it like this.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use WPF only in a DX application if you let WPF do the compositing and presentation. You can't use your own swapchain.

Comment: I think you are right, thanks!